# installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status in R 3.6.0

Tags: r, package, install.packages

I try to install `car` package in Windows version of `R 3.6.0`. I use Windows 8.1. I got following error message: `installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status`

Full output:

```
> install.packages("car")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Zsófia/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
    binary source needs_compilation
car  3.0-2  3.0-3             FALSE

installing the source package ‘car’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/car_3.0-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 539020 bytes (526 KB)
downloaded 526 KB

* installing *source* package 'car' ...
** package 'car' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Zssfia/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-car/00new/car/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'car'
* removing 'C:/Users/Zsófia/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/car'

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\Zsófia\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpK0Qk4Q\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("car") :
  installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
```

Other packages, like `psych` are successfully installed.

Comment: If you're prompted to answer yes or no to installing from source, and it didn't work to answer "yes" (which it looks like you did), try answering "no"

Comment: @camille : I haven't been asked, I just installed it on other machine and haven't seen a message like this.

Comment: @camille : Thanks, I tried it with type="binary" and it was successfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For windows, try version 3.0.2 of the car package.

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/car_3.0-2.zip",
                 lib = .libPaths()[1], repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
packageVersion("car")

package ‘car’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> packageVersion("car")
[1] ‘3.0.2’
```

Comment: Just to update, as the version 3.0.2 is not available on the site anymore. I happen to have the same problem so I tried browsing back to https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/, and found that the version 3.0-7 is there. It works for me.

In short, change the first command to `install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/car_3.0-7.zip", lib = .libPaths()[1], repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")`